# Computer simulation of evolution process

Tags: python

How can I simulate and map special position of some moving bacteria(square or capsule) in a 2D space in python.I tried how the capsules were dividing using standard simulation with time. But unable to map their special position in a 2D space. I just want to simulate the colony growth of bacteria.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are storing their current positions, if you have a list of locations you can use matplotlib's scatter to plot the locations of all bacteria in 2d. You can also give colour to the bacteria using the same command.

If instead you have a array/matrix representation of the space you can use matplotlibs imshow command, but make sure to set interpolation='Nearest' or it will look very blurry.

Comment: For list of location, how can I overcome the overlapping problem? And at the end of the simulation, I have to visualize the colony for fractal dimension calculation..

Comment: If by the overlapping problem you mean bacteria being on top of each other, then you have two options you either have a grid based CA which doesnt allow this or have continuous space and simply plot them on top of each other. 

While I have constructed a 2d cellular automation, I have never calculated the fractal dimension of one so i cannot help you there.

Comment: Can you please help me to construct a 2D CA with dividing bacterial cell...forming a colony

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I have the code for capsule[cell] division.**Now how I placed a capsule in a single point of a 2D array?** Then I have to chose its neighbours vacant cell for replication..I think Moore neighbour can be applied here.